# What does R 2 dots "..something.." do?

Tags: r, data-visualization, geom-bar

I am learning R for visualization, and come across this example:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = 1))
```

The result will show proportionally instead of count, but I don't understand how this works. Could someone please explain to me what is this syntax `..something..`do ?

Comment: The `..xxx..` construction represents variables computed internally by ggplot. For example, look  at the "computed variables" section of the [help for `geom_bar`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).

Comment: Is it specific to ggplot ? or Is it something meaningful in R? why not just `y = prop`

Comment: It's specific to ggplot. I'm not certain of the reason for the `..`, but I'd guess it was to avoid confusion with other functions or objects that have the same name.

Comment: The `..` notation was deprecated in the latest release of `ggplot2` in favor of `stat()`

Comment: Sure it's somewhat duplicated, but why downvote ?

Comment: @camille: how would you write the above statement in `ggplot2` with `stat()` ?

Comment: You would use it like `stat(prop)` instead of `..prop..`. It's documented at `?stat`